# How to inject properties from application.yml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have some application.yml file:

```
main-prop:
  sub-prop:
    name: test
    password: test1

    data:
      prop1: 1
      prop2: 0
```

and classes:

```
abstract class abscractPropertyHolder {
    private String namePattern;
    private String categoryPattern;
    private String departmentPattern;
    private Data data;
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("main-prop")
class ReconfigurationEventFilterConfig extends abscractPropertyHolder {
}

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
class Data {   // if my class is public - my app run successfully, otherwise fail to start (exception).
    private int prop1;
    private int prop2;

    static DatanewInstanceWithDefaultParameters() {
        return new Data().setProp1(1).setProp2(0);
    }
}
```

I have this exception:

```
Could not instantiate property type [com.test.Data] to auto-grow nested property path; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [com.test.Data]: Is the constructor accessible?;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
Class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils can not access a member of class 
com.test.Data with modifiers "public"
```

All classes places in the one package. I don't want to make my Data class public. How can I inject data from application.yml?

Comment: what is wrong with making the class public? Everything in spring ends up as a bean so it would be accesible to anything anyway.

Comment: @maslan this is classes must work only with one package and I don't want to make it public.

Comment: then use @Value(PROPERTY_NAME) annotation over your fields, and make getters and setters that are not public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem like this:

I added the spring annotation `@Autowired` to the abscractPropertyHolder class and added spring annotation `@ConfigurationProperties("main-prop.sub-prop.data")` to the Data class.

```
abstract class abscractPropertyHolder {
    private String namePattern;
    private String categoryPattern;
    private String departmentPattern;
    @Autowired
    private Data data;
}

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@ConfigurationProperties("main-prop.sub-prop.data")
class Data {   // if my class is public - my app run successfully, otherwise fail to 
start (exception).
    private int prop1;
    private int prop2;

    static DatanewInstanceWithDefaultParameters() {
        return new Data().setProp1(1).setProp2(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Format yml like this:

```
main-prop:
    sub-prop:
      name: test
      password: test1

      data:
        prop1: 1
        prop2: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Data` makes use of `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. Try to define the behaviour of the `@Data` annotation by overriding the visibility of the constructor it creates:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
```

Having `@Data` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, Lombok will use the access level you define.

Either this or try to define a `@NoArgsConstructor`.

Comment: I try this one, but it's not helped to me I get the same exception.

Comment: @Oleg have you tried defining the accessors/constructors by hand instead of using Lombok? Also run delombok to check which code is being generated automatically. It might not be in the format expected by Spring

Comment: I removed Lombok annotations from Data class, but it has no effect. I get the same exception.

Comment: You removed the annotations but, just to make sure, did you create the getters and setters by hand?

Comment: yes I'm made getters/setters and constructors by hand.